# Understanding an example about homomorphism

Tags: order-theory

[image]

Let $X=\left\{ a,b,c\right\}$ be a set and $R=\left\{ (a,b),(a,c)\right\}$ a relation on $X$; and let $Y=\left\{ u,v\right\}$ be a set and $S=\left\{ (u,v)\right\}$ a relation on $Y$.

A homomorphism is a map $f:X\to Y$ with the property $(f(x),f(y))\in S$ whenever $(x,y)\in R$.

Any homomorphism must take $a$ to $u$ and $b$ and $c$ to $v$.

**My question is: If it was take $a$ to $v$ and $b$ and $c$ to $u$ then is it homomorphism? If no, why?**

Comment: I'm not following the notation $Y=\{M,V\}$. What are $M$ and $V$?

Comment: Homomorphism of whats?

Comment: @TheCount edited.

Comment: @VikrantDesai Edited. It is a graph and it is a graph homomorphism.

Comment: Edited again...

Comment: Are we sure it's not a directed graph?  $(a,b)$ usually denotes an ordered pair, and nowhere does it say the relation is symmetric...  If that's the case then the diagram is missing arrows which would clear things up.

Comment: @DanBrumleve $(a,b)$ means $a$ related to $b$ and $b$ related to $a$,it is symmetric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A homomorphism needs to preserve existing edges, but it has no problems adding new edges, or "merging points" if conditions are right.

Since both $b$ and $c$ are maximal elements with the same minimum as the only point below them, mapping both of them to $v$ is indeed a homomorphism.

On the other hand, if we map $a$ to $v$, and both $b$ and $c$ to $u$, then we don't have a homomorphism, since $a\mathrel{R}b$, but $v\not\mathrel{S}u$ which means $f(a)\not\mathrel{S}f(b)$. And this means that $f$ will not be a homomorphism.

You might argue that if we reverse the order then it works, and you'd be correct. And this property is sometimes called an anti-homomorphism; or an order-reversing function.

Comment: You said that $v$ is not related to $u$, why? Is it symetric?

Comment: Because $x$ relates to $y$ if and only if $(x,y)$ is an ordered pair of the relation. This is not a symmetric relation, this is a partial order.

Comment: And if it is a symmetric relation, then the entire thing is entirely unclear from your question, and you should definitely ask this to whomever gave you this information in the first place, as they have the correct context and information to give you the correct answer.

Comment: You are right. It is not symmetric since it is ordered pair of the relation. Thanks.